# Using two arrays in UITableview swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have Two labels in one cell and two arrays in one table view , I want to link Each array with label

list [ ] with la_view and list_2 [ ] with la_view2 ,
also la_view and la_view2 in one cell in table view

When running the program shows Error As shown .

```
var list = [String]()
var list_2 = [String]()

func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return list.count + list_2.count

}

func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_1") as! TableView_Cell
        print("\(list.count)")
        cell.la_view.text = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.la_view2.text = list_2[indexPath.row] // eroor here
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Defeult")
        return cell
}

// This append in arrays
func append(add:Int) {
    list.append("\(add)")
    list_2.append("\(add)")
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: list.count - 1, section: 0)
    let indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: list_2.count - 1, section: 0)
    table_View.beginUpdates()
    table_View.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    table_View.insertRows(at: [indexPath2], with: .automatic)
    table_View.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. Don't use multiple arrays as data source

```
return list.count + list_2.count
```

causes the error because actually you have only `list.count` number of items where `list.count` must be equal to `list_2.count`. The addition raises an out-of-range exception at row `list.count + 1`

Use a custom struct

```
struct Item {
    let foo : String
    let bar : String
}
```

Then map the two arrays

```
var items = [Item]()

items = zip(list, list_2).map{ Item(foo:$0.0, bar:$0.1) }
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return  `items.count`

In `cellForRowAt` get the value from the `Item` instance

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
cell.la_view.text = item.foo
cell.la_view2.text = item.bar
```

To append an item use

```
func append(add:Int) {
    let lastIndex = items.count
    items.append( Item(foo:"\(add)", bar:"\(add)") )
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastIndex, section: 0)
    table_View.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

And please according to the naming convention use *lowerCamelCased* rather than *snake_cased* variable names.

Comment: Then map the tow arrays , where write this ?

Comment: This is only a quick example how to simply combine the arrays. You should populate the data source array by creating `Item` instances directly. And `Item` is an example, too. Use a more meaningful name.

Comment: I was going to suggest using an array of tulples for a quick solution but as stated above a custom object is the way to go. Multiple arrays in a tableView is just asking for issues, and indexpath out of range errors.